# How to merge two collections into one

Tags: .net, silverlight, generics, collections

I have two collections created within Silverlight each collection is created at separate times by different methods.

Method 1 creates a  List<> titled person ( contains fields first name, last name age)

Method 2 created a List<> titled Phone ( contains phone number, cell number)

Is there a way within SL to combine these two Lists into one Collection that could then be bound to the view for display?

Example: combined into a collection that contained all properties (first name, last name age, phone number, cell number)

Comment: What is the relationship between the two lists, i.e. common key, sequential order?

Comment: I have a objectId referred to as related ID. the thing that is screwy is this is from an abastracted database so there are no direct relational links assoications are set at the field level. I can the good think is the data is alwasy 1:1 so when method 1 fires followed by method 2 I alwasy know that results retuned from are are related. I just need to merge them into one collection

Comment: I think @JaredPar's answer should work for you then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `Zip` function.  It allows you to combine 2 collections into a single one by combining the elements of eache.

```
List<Type1> col1 = ...;
List<Type2> col2 = ...;
var combined = col1.Zip(col2, (x, y) => new {
  FirstName = x.FirstName,
  LastName = x.LastName,
  PhoneNumber = y.PhoneNumber,
  CellNumber = y.CellNumber });
```

I'm not sure if Zip is available on not in Silverlight.  If not then here's a definition of it

```
public static IEnumerable<TRet> Zip<T1, T2, TRet>(
  this IEnumerable<T1> enumerable1, 
  IEnumerable<T2> enumreable2,
  Func<T1, T2, TRet> func) {

  using (var e1 = enumerable1.GetEnumerator()) {
    using (var e2 = enumerable2.GetEnumerator()) {
      while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext()) {  
        yield return func(e1.Current, e2.Current);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankss JaredPar Zip does work in SL. Any quick tips on  how can I convert this abstract type back to a collection that I can promote to the view?